# Disabling half of a UIStepper

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, delegates, uistepper

I have a set of steppers than when added up they're supposed to give an X-amount. They're all in a UICollectionview and I used delegates to pass values between them and the ViewController.
You're supposed to allocate points among different players, once you reach the total number of points you were given to allocate you can no longer "add" points. I want to disable "half" of the stepper once the total number of points is reached. How can I do this? (without disabling the whole stepper, since the user might want to re-allocate points and return some of its points back).

Here's my code so far:

```
    protocol CollectionVCDelegate: class {
        func usedPoints() -> Int
        func returnPoints() -> Int
    }
    class PointAllocationVC: UIViewController, CollectionVCDelegate {

        func usedPoints() -> Int {
            pointsToAllocate -= 1
            totalPointsLabel.text = String(pointsToAllocate)
            return pointsToAllocate
        }

        func returnPoints() -> Int
        {
            pointsToAllocate += 1
            totalPointsLabel.text = String(pointsToAllocate)
            return pointsToAllocate
        }
    var pointsToAllocate: Int = 5 //may change, 5 for example
    @IBOutlet weak var ptsAllocView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var totalPointsLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var addAllButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var ptAllocCollectionView: UICollectionView!
}

extension PointAllocationVC: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource
{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return currentPlayers.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let myptCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ptsCell", for: indexPath) as! PtsAllocationViewCell
        myptCell.playerNameLabel.text = currentPlayers[indexPath.row]
        myptCell.playerScoreLabel.text = "Score: \(currentScore[indexPath.row])"
        myptCell.delegate = self

        if indexPath.row == 0
        {
            myptCell.ptsAllocStepper.minimumValue = 0
        }
        else
        {
            myptCell.ptsAllocStepper.maximumValue = 0
            myptCell.isSelf = false
        }

        return myptCell
    }
}
```

Now, here's the code for the ViewCells:

```
import UIKit

class PtsAllocationViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    var delegate: CollectionVCDelegate? = nil
    var isSelf = true
    var ptsRemaining: Int = 0
    @IBOutlet weak var ptsLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var playerNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var playerScoreLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ptsAllocStepper: UIStepper!
    @IBAction func stepperTapped(_ sender: UIStepper) {
        let myInt: Int = Int(ptsLabel.text!)!
        if delegate != nil
        {
            if isSelf
            {
                if myInt > Int(sender.value)
                {
                    ptsRemaining = (delegate?.returnPoints())!
                }
                else
                {
                    ptsRemaining = (delegate?.usedPoints())!
                }

            }
            else
            {
                if myInt > Int(sender.value)
                {
                    ptsRemaining = (delegate?.usedPoints())!
                }
                else
                {
                    ptsRemaining = (delegate?.returnPoints())!
                }
            }
        }
        ptsLabel.text = String(Int(sender.value))
    }

}
```

NOTE: This code works so far as much as I want it to (as far as adding/subtracting from the ViewController pointsToAllocate and updating labels and all. However, as of now there are no locks preventing the user form over-usings points (say he can put 5 on each and have a total of -15 points at the end, you shouldn't be able to go below 0)

and just for added clarity here's a picture, note it will have around 4 - 6 different "players":
[image: storyboard of ViewController]

Answer (score 0):

<s>You probably cannot "disable the + side"...</s>

Options:

1. Use two buttons, instead of a stepper. Disable the "+" button as desired, or
2. Set the Increment Image to indicate it's disabled when you want to disable it, and just don't process the "+" taps.
3. Each side of the `UIStepper` will be automatically disabled when it reaches its min or max value. See the answer from @the4kman

Answer (score 0):

Set all the steppers' `maximumValue` to the total number of points, minus the points that were already allocated **each time when a stepper's value changes**. You should observe `UIControlEvents.valueChanged` for that.

That way, the stepper's **+** half will be disabled if you reach the maximum amount of points.

[image: UIStepper with + half disabled]

Comment: Hi the4kman, that would work if I only had 1 stepper. However since I have 4+ steppers, if each one had a max value of the total number of points then i have 4x as many points to allocate. The only way would be to "dynamically" change the max values, say if I use 1 point all steppers have 1 point less as max (except the one that already used one)

Comment: @the4kman - ah... I didn't realize the stepper auto-disables the side if the stepper is at its min or max value. Good to know.